# Зависание программы при заполнении QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Два слоя: один верхний, другой нижний.
При динамическом добавлении элементов в QGridLayout зависает.
Подскажите в чем проблема.

```
topLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

comboBox = new QComboBox();
label = new QLabel("Z = ");

topLayout->addWidget(comboBox);
topLayout->addWidget(label);

for(int i = 0; i <= col; i++)
{
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit("0");
    topLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
}

leftGrid = new QGridLayout();
//lineEdit = NULL;

for(int i = 0; i <= row; row++)
    for(int j = 0; j <= col; col++)
    {
        lineEdit = new QLineEdit("0");
        leftGrid->addWidget(lineEdit, i, j);

    }


mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
mainLayout->addLayout(topLayout);
mainLayout->addLayout(leftGrid);

this->setLayout(mainLayout);
```

Comment: Я вот смотрю код и думается что вы пытаетесь `QTableWidget` повторить :)  А еще то, что у вас условие нестандартное -- ожидаемое значение строк и столбцов будет на 1 больше (из-за начального 0 и условия меньше или равно). Да и тот двойной цикл очееень подозрительный. Точно нужно именно `row` и `col` инкрементировать? А то у вас это похоже на бесконечный цикл. В общем, попробуйте код из ответа, думаю поможет с тем зависанием

Comment: спасибо большое я тупанул жестко

Comment: бывает :) если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте его :)

Comment: QTableWidget - некрасиво

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
topLayout = new QHBoxLayout();

comboBox = new QComboBox();
label = new QLabel("Z = ");

topLayout->addWidget(comboBox);
topLayout->addWidget(label);

for (int i = 0; i <= col; i++)
{
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit("0");
    topLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
}

leftGrid = new QGridLayout();

for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++)
    {
        lineEdit = new QLineEdit("0");
        leftGrid->addWidget(lineEdit, i, j);
    }
}


mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
mainLayout->addLayout(topLayout);
mainLayout->addLayout(leftGrid);

setLayout(mainLayout);
```